# Collapse a log by date into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, aggregate, grouping

A local variable named log contains an array of hashes with timestamped events like so:

```
log = [
  {time: 201201, x: 2},
  {time: 201201, y: 7},
  {time: 201201, z: 2},
  {time: 201202, a: 3},
  {time: 201202, b: 4},
  {time: 201202, c: 0}
]
```

I need to collapse the log by date into an array of hashes containing one entry per day:

```
result = [
  {time: 201201, x: 2, y: 7, z: 2},
  {time: 201202, a: 3, b: 4, c: 0},
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
log.group_by {|e| e[:time] }.map {|_,v| v.reduce(:merge) }
```

Comment: @sawa true enough, though it's a special case for reduce/inject.

Comment: Wow! This is that I was trying to do. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
log.each_with_object({}) do |e, a|
  (a[e[:time]] ||= {}).merge!(e)
end.values
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one. But it does not look as pretty as the other. 
Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} } could help a bit ...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem but I'm not happy with this solution. Seems to be useful the [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method for this kind of problem.

```
log.inject([]) do |acc, elem|
  time = elem[:time]
  found_by_time = acc.select {|hash| hash.any? {|i| i.include?(time)}}
  found_by_time.empty? ? acc << elem : found_by_time.first.merge!(elem)
  acc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log = [
  {time: 201201, x: 2},
  {time: 201201, y: 7},
  {time: 201201, z: 2},
  {time: 201202, a: 3},
  {time: 201202, b: 4},
  {time: 201202, c: 0}
]

answer = log.reduce([]) do |result, value|
  d = result.select {|h| h.any? {|i| i.include?(value[:time])}}
  if d.empty? 
    result << value 
  else
    d.first.merge!(value) 
  end
  result
end

 #=>{:time=>201201, :x=>2, :y=>7, :z=>2}
 #=>{:time=>201202, :a=>3, :b=>4, :c=>0}
```